# Cant parse string to datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2011-05-25 24:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

for some reason parsing this string to a datetime does not want to work. I Tried several things already but it just does not want to work. Most of the internet examples do it like this too. 
Does someone sees what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: It's probably the 24:00:00 try 00:00:00 instead

Comment: 24? Hours should be in 0 to 23 range.

Comment: java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has `H` for (0 - 23) and `k` for (1 - 24). I wonder if .NET has anything like that.

Comment: @Bala: no, there is nothing like that in .NET (at least not that I am aware of).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"24:00:00"` is not a valid time. Should probably be `"00:00:00"`. If you meant the second that comes after `2011-05-25 23:59:59`, that would be `2011-05-26 00:00:00`.

For more information about valid value ranges for different format specifiers, check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) at MSDN.